# interaction of R with RESTful APIs

Tags: r, rest, restful-url

In my project the data sent via RESTful APIs are to be received with R.So for this there is a REST server and a rest client.The rest client talks with the server repetedly for updated data(a timer of certain time is set).The data format received from the API is in json format. My question is how can I connect R with this REST client.So that every time the data is updated ,R ll get the updated data through the REST client.After this I need to store the data in a database in tabular form.how to receive data continuously and store it in database.

Comment: This question is a bit vague, but you might find [opencpu](https://www.opencpu.org/) interesting. It provides a *stateless* RESTful API of R packages/functions that communicates using (optionally) JSON as an encoding standard. If you need *stateful*, you'll need to craft something using Rserve.

Comment: BTW, *stateless* means you'll need to write an R function that accepts data and uploads it to a database *and then exits*. Problems you'll be faced with: time-to-connect (and potential for timeout), storage of authentication credentials/tokens, correctness of user-supplied data. Though it can work, I suggest the possibility that R is not the ideal language for this portion of your project. (Many might suggest python or java. If this is large scale, it might fit well with kafka or some other streaming framework such as Hadoop/Spark.)